# Installing library on python

Tags: python

I am trying to download a library on python but It says `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/speech_recognition'`
What should I do?

Comment: Try with the --user option Then tell me the result

Comment: Run the command with administrator permission

Comment: How can I do that? By directing the library somewhere?

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe I think that it worked with the sudo command.

Comment: How can I check

Comment: maybe some more details to understand your cases would be helpful for us to help you. _How_ are you trying to download the library? Do you use pip? do you use an IDE, if yes, which one?

Comment: I use the command "pip install SpeechRecognition" an I am using the VSCode

Comment: on Linux "permission error" is likely to be solved by using `sudo`, for _any_ software error.

Comment: Apparently it worked with the administration command "sudo", but how can I check it

Comment: If t is downloaded

Comment: @Miles check my answer

Comment: BTW, I am trying install text to speech library "pip install pyttsx3" but it says ''' SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/km/sv51fl4d30g668xtstm8_lzh0000gq/T/pip_build_F.Gorkem/pyobjc/setup.py", line 536

    print(f"Framework {fwk} not in framework-wrappers.rst")
SyntaxError: invalid syntax'''.  what should I do?

Comment: As I cannot post another question, I wrote it here.

Comment: @Miles Why not? just post another question

Comment: because I have to wait 90 minutes

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that...

Comment: No problem, But what should I do?

Comment: wait 90 min, and during this time try other things, like search for the error message (the generic part). I have a feeling it might be due to a python version mismatch (python 2.7 versus python 3)

Comment: Please post *all* the steps and information you have *as part of the question itself*. You can always [edit] it to add more details.

Comment: I got the resolution of the problem, so where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by `sudo` command

then, check it by

```
> python
some text will appear here
>>> import [yourlibraryname]
```

Like this. then check for any errors